# Как создать exe файл используя python и selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pyinstaller, web-scraping

Уже всю ночь гуглил, никак не могу понять как создать exe-шник в один файл используя selenium.
У меня есть такой код:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

def parse():
    keywords = input("Write keywords: ")

    driver = webdriver.Chrome('./driver/chromedriver.exe', options=Options())
    driver.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)

    for key in keywords.split(","):
        driver.get(f"https://www.google.com/search?q={key}&tbm=shop")
        names = []

        try:
            is_load = bool(driver.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "aULzUe"))))
            name_blocks = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "aULzUe")
            for i in name_blocks:
                if i.text not in names:
                    names.append(i.text)
        except Exception as error:
            print(f"This keyword '{key}' isn't correct!!!\nThe problem is {error}")
            continue

        with open(f"{key}.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
            for name in names:
               file.write(name + "\n")
    driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        parse()
    except Exception as er:
        answer = input(f"The problem is {er}")
```

Я уже пробовал и добавление chromedriver через pyinstaller (--add-binary), ссылаясь на вот эту статью https://www.zacoding.com/en/post/python-selenium-to-exe/
и менял получившийся spec файл также добавляя туда chromedriver вот таким образом:

```
a = Analysis(...
     binaries=[ ( './driver/chromedriver.exe', './driver' ) ],
```

Каждый раз я получаю один и тот-же результат - создаеться exe файл, но пытаясь его открыть он тут же закрывается с ошибкой:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'C:\\Users\\E8E5~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI13282\\selenium\\webdriver\\re 
mote\\getAttribute.js'
[2004] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!
```

Вот список всех актуальный версий моего проэкта:

```
selenium == 4.1.0
pyinstaller == 4.7
pip == 21.1.2
Python == 3.9.4
```

Answer (score 0):

можешь попробовать webdriver_manager

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).